# HPLIP: fax driver lost connection with printer

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, 19.10, hplip

Kubuntu 19.10

HPLIP installed by download from the vendor's website.

The printer has a wired ethernet connection.

I am trying to run print-to-fax, and it used to work, but now I am getting error messages. Removing and re-adding the printer doesn't help.

Let me mention that Windows  has no trouble running print-to-fax jobs on this printer, using "HP Universal Fax Driver", so I don't think the problem lies with the printer.

The HPLIP troubleshooter says (I pasted the most relevant section first):

```
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hpfax:/net/Officejet_Pro_6830?ip=XXX
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.12)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.12)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.



Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found


Checking for HPLIP updates....

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.12)
HPLIP upgrade latest version ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Latest version of HPLIP is already installed.


Checking for Dependencies....

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 GNU/Linux
 Host: shmuel-Kubuntu
 Proc: 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 19.10
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.19.12
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  19.10 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.19.12

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.19.12
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.19.12
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.19.12
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
qt5=no
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
latest_available_version = 3.17.10
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1578252103
pending_upgrade_time = 0

[settings]
systray_visible = 0
systray_messages = 2

[last_used]
device_uri = "hpfax:/net/Officejet_Pro_6830?ip=XXX"
printer_name = Officejet_Pro_6830_fax
working_dir = .

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = false
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list = 

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address = 

[installation]
date_time = 01/14/20 09:20:14
version = 3.19.12


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.2.12          OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.27            OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.27          OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.14         OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.2.12          OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.2.12          OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.30'         OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.7.5           OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 python3-pyqt4-dbus   PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 python3-pyqt4        PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.12          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.7.5           OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               6.1.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.5.23          OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.2.1           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.19.12         OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.19.12         OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.19.12         OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.19.12         OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/net/officejet_pro_6830?ip=XXX&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard officejet_pro_6830 all-in-one


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------


HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_
-----------------------------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: implicitclass://HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_/
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_ is idle.  enabled since Tue 14 Jan 2020 08:42:14 AM IST
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.

Officejet_Pro_6830_fax
----------------------
Type: Fax
Device URI: hpfax:/net/Officejet_Pro_6830?ip=XXX
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/Officejet_Pro_6830_fax.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/Officejet_Pro_6830_fax.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer Officejet_Pro_6830_fax is idle.  enabled since Fri 10 Jan 2020 09:54:06 AM IST
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hpfax:/net/Officejet_Pro_6830?ip=XXX
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------



Checking Permissions....


Checking for Configured Queues....
warning: Fail to read ppd=/etc/cups/ppd/HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_.ppd file
warning: Insufficient permission to access file /etc/cups/ppd/HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_.ppd
warning: Could not complete Queue(s) configuration check


Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.


Checking for Printer Status....
error: 'Officejet_Pro_6830_fax' Printer is either Powered-OFF or Failed to communicate.
Turn On Printer and re-run hp-doctor

Diagnose completed...



More information on Troubleshooting,How-To's and Support is available on http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html


Please close this terminal manually.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_
-----------------------------
Type: Unknown
Device URI: implicitclass://HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_/
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer HP_Officejet_Pro_6830_C9CB08_ is idle.  enabled since Tue 14 Jan 2020 08:42:14 AM IST
warning: Printer is not HPLIP installed. Printers must use the hp: or hpfax: CUPS backend for HP-Devices.
```

If you set up printer through System Settings

it may not have set up properly.

You must run the hp-setup wizard

```
sudo hp-setup
```

1. For Connection Type choose "Network/Ethernet..."
2. If the device is not detected, click "Show advanced options", tick
   "Manual discovery" and supply the scanner's IP address.

Install hplip-gui

```
sudo apt install hplip-gui
```

From Application Launcher open Hplip-Toolbox

Select HP "name of printer"(Fax)

Under Actions tab select Send Fax

And follow the steps.

In step three you. When you use print to fax from another application it should appear and you will be ready to send.

Tested this with Kubuntu 18.04 and a HP Color Laserjet 2840

Comment: I added the printer using hp-setup wizard and "Network/Ethernet", and indeed, it works... but only for a while. Randomly, after a reboot or after a couple days, it loses connection with the printer. I had the same problem on Linux Mint. It would work for a while, and then glitch out, at which point, reinstallation of HPLIP and/or removing and adding the printer doesn't help.

Comment: You may have better luck assigning it a static ip address through you router. If the ip of the printer is changed for any reason the printer will usually need a reboot to detect the new ip it has been assigned. In my case that solved issues. This was effecting windows compters also in my case

Comment: I tried connecting the printer by usb, and I had the same issue, so I don't think the ip address is the real problem here.

Comment: I will try to recreate  the problem in a VM and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: I have tested on 19.10 with `hplip` versions(3.19.6) and(3.19.12). I have not been able to reproduce your issues. Specifically the permission issues I noticed at the bottom of your post. Your security policy may differ. I have seen some bug reports that may help you. [Debian Bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=hplip-gui;dist=unstable), [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/702934). In those reports I noticed similar permission issues that may relate to your proplem.

Comment: HP does not provide telephone support for Linux printing. All support is provided online at the following web page: [hpDevelopers](https://launchpad.net/hplip). On that page, click the "Ask a question" section.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I posted a question on hpDevelopers.